# Nodejs Couchbase deserialize date property from document

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

I'm saving in Couchbase a document which has javascript Date values, and wish to get it exactly the same, not as string '2016-01-02T12:13:14Z'.

Found a way to achieve this using plain Javascript, by using the second parameter of [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) , but Couchbase does the deserialization internally and can't really use this.

Is there any way to disable the Couchbase deserialization, and to avoid doing `JSON.stringify` + `JSON.parse` and neither deep-walking the object?

```
bucket.get(key, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        //deal with error here
    } else {
        //here "result.value" is already deserialized
        done(result.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, JSON and Date object handling can be a bit specific depending on what you're trying to do.  We tend to stick to the defaults.  What you're looking for is a fairly advanced use case.  At the moment, we don't have direct support for changing the way we do that parsing.

However, there is an interface for this.  It's called a "transcoder" and it lets you be very specific about how you want to handle converting incoming data to what is stored.  I don't have an example that shows quite what you want to do, but a good place to start looking for this at a lower layer is [shown in the tests](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/7026d5d10f6b046dcda2a1b3cbf20ce23d694414/test/transcoders.test.js).

It might be easier, however, to just treat whatever you're storing differently at the application level.  From my read of the revivier parameter you pointed to, that'd be only at time of retrieval.  There's nothing stopping you from wrapping that get() and then mutating the object before passing it along to the next layer at very low cost I do believe.